# Sending all the value from Listview A to B

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

In Activity A, I have a listView and an action bar icon used to intent to Activity B. If listView is pressed, it will send all the value from A to B and display on editText.

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                Expenses o = (Expenses) obj.getItem(position);
                String day = o.getDate(); // 4 Dec 2016
                String[] split = day.split("\\s+");
                String date= split[1]; // 4 
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuickExpenses.this,AddExpenses.class);
                intent.putExtra("date",date);
                intent.putExtra("month", month); // Dec 2016
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_add_task:
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuickExpenses.this, AddExpenses.class);
                intent.putExtra("month", month); // Dec 2016
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }
         }
```

**Activity B**

Activity B has an editText. When editText is pressed it will pop out datePickerDialog, for user select the date.

```
EditText date;
String month;

date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month");

 if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A (listView pressed)
            String mDay = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
            date.setText(mDay + "" + month);
        }
```

So if the listview is pressed, it will display 5 Dec 2016 in `EditText` date. But the problem is when I click the icon in Activity A, it display `null Dec 2016` . I want to clear the `editText` by using `date.setText("")` and `date.getText().clear();` but it still showing `null Dec 2016`.

> I want date `editText` display nothing if icon Activity A pressed but not
>   `null Dec 2016`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is your passing intent in both cases so that is why it is going inside this block

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A (listView pressed)
            String mDay = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
            date.setText(mDay + "" + month);
        }
```

so just change your if condition with below code

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("date")!=null) { //if  has value pass from A (listView pressed)
            String mDay = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
            date.setText(mDay + "" + month);
        }
  else {
            date.setText("");
      }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: you can make it more simple just remove else that is also not needed

Comment: but i need date.setText("");

Comment: it will be by default "". you dont have to set it intentionally

Answer (score 2):

**Check below code :**

```
    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A (listView pressed)
                String mDay = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mDay) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(month)){
date.setText(mDay + "" + month);
    }

            }
```

Comment: I want date `editText` display nothing if icon Activity A pressed.

Comment: *date* is EditText in your code. Am i correct? Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Yes, _date_ is EditText

Comment: Have you tried my code?. I think it will work for you. You should not get null Dec 2016.

Comment: Yes, no null , but still getting Dec 2016. How to remove them?

Comment: Welcome :)  TextUtils class is very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

**On click Activity A remove  intent.putExtra("month", month);on Icon click and in Activity B try bellow code**

```
 date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
 month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month");
 mDay = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");

    if(getIntent().getExtras()=null) { //if  has value pass from A (listView pressed)

               date.setText("");
            }
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following snippet!

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_add_task:
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuickExpenses.this, AddExpenses.class);
            intent.putExtra("date", ""); // Dec 2016
            intent.putExtra("month", month); // Dec 2016
            startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: This is not a solution! you just pass an empty value for date

Comment: I want date `editText` display nothing if icon Activity A pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Code , 
some value (Variable month,ie may be holding the value Dec 2016) is send using intent when you are clicking on the icon in Action bar

remove

```
intent.putExtra("month", month); // Dec 2016
```

from `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: I need it because in date `editText`, I want user select date only

Answer (score 0):

You must check the intent from listview or icon.From your code can check from mDay is empty or not.If mDay is empty it's form icon pressed.

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { 
      String month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month");
      String mDay = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mDay)
          date.setText(mDay + "" + month);
      else // mDay will empty from icon click.
          date.setText("");

 }
```

Comment: Please add a textual explanation and do not just provide a code snippet.